# jQuery load method gives status cancelled

Tags: jquery

I m using jQuery load method to load some pages to get their meta data; such as title, description etc. Since this seems an easy method for that.

But everytime a request is made by jQuery method to any URL, it gets a status of cancel. Why is that happening? Is that something related to browser or the server prevents it?

My code that I am using is:

```
$('.link').load('http://' +$('#link').val(), function (response, status, xhr) {
   if (status == 'error') {
     $('.linkinfo').html('Not a valid link!');
   } else {
     $('.linkinfo').html($(response).filter('title').text());
   }
 });
```

The HTML code for that is:

```
<input type="text" id="link" onkeyup="" />
<div class="linkinfo"></div>
<div class="link"></div>
```

Where the input will be any of the link such as `www.google.com` or `www.facebook.com`. I just want to take out the meta data of their. But the `status == 'error'` block gets executed each time.

I keep a note on each request made using Network tab from Developer tools. Which is cancelled in Chrome and Moved temporarily in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Can we see the HTML for the input?

Comment: Sure you can, its a simply input!

Comment: I just realized: You are trying to go out and fetch a non-local website... that won't work, due to cross-domain restrictions.

Comment: So how does Facebook and Tumblr and other majors get the meta data? Is there any way to fetch that?

Comment: They probably use a local proxy that uses server layer technology to fetch that data.

Comment: Ooh, thnks for the idea! :) Will try to Google that! :)

Comment: if you check the jQuery load() method - **http://api.jquery.com/load/** - `Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.`

Comment: @jonathan, thanks for this note :) will keep this in mind for future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be a **same origin policy**:

if you check the jQuery **load()** method under **Additional Notes**

api.jquery.com/load

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

**same origin policy:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy